# Django-filter | Boolean fields

Tags: python, django, django-filter

I'm using django-filter package and I have many boolean fields.
Is there a way to filter only when field is True? And show all other posibilities?

For example if I have 3 fields: True, False, False... Render objects that have 1st field equal True but doesn't matter about de rest, don't consider it False.

**model.py**

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    is_dangerous = models.BooleanField()
    is_secret = models.BooleanField()
    is_active = models.BooleanField()
```

**filters.py**

```
class SearchFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    name = django_filters.CharFilter(lookup_expr='icontains')
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['name', 'is_dangerous', 'is_secret', 'is_active',]
        filter_overrides = {
            models.BooleanField: {
                'filter_class': django_filters.BooleanFilter,
                'extra': lambda f: {
                    'widget': forms.CheckboxInput,
                },
            },
        }
```

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^products/$', views.products, name='products')
```

When I enter to `products/` for the first time, I only see products that has all boolean fields = False and I want to see ALL products.

Comment: have you tried something? put it in question

Comment: I've updated the question with my example

Answer (score 14):

You don't need all of that filter stuff. To filter models based on the value of a BooleanField all you need is

```
dangerous_products = Product.objects.filter(is_dangerous=True)
```

This will return a QuerySet of all model instances with `is_dangerous` set to `True`.

You can then pass this variable to your template and display the information like this

```
{% for product in dangerous_product %}
    <!-- Put whatever way you want to display each product in here. EX:-->
    <h1>{{ product.name }}</h1>
{% endfor %}
```

The above template will display the name of every product with `is_dangerous` set to `True`.

Comment: I know this, but I need a search engine in the platform that users can modify

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use `CheckboxInput`s, as the widget is not able to distinguish between "not present" and "false". Simply remove the filter override and use the default select widget.

Comment: Yes, I have some other fields which have diferent options (select) but I also need some checkboxes; and I need the first time to be "any" like select options

Comment: What I'm saying is that `CheckboxInput` doesn't work, since an unchecked input is equivalent to "false". This occurs even when you haven't submitted the form. The CBV always binds the FilterSet with data (even if empty).

Instead, you should use something like a `RadioSelect` with yes/no choices, or a simple dropdown select.

Answer (score 0):

For effective boolean filtering, you have to use

```py
from django_filters import rest_framework as filters
```

```py
class SearchFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    name = django_filters.CharFilter(lookup_expr='icontains')
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['name', 'is_dangerous', 'is_secret', 'is_active',]
```

Answer (score 0):

### Add the argument `method`

You can add the `method` argument in every attribute like this:

```
class SearchFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    name = django_filters.CharFilter(lookup_expr='icontains')
    is_dangerous = django_filters.BooleanFilter(
        widget=CheckboxInput(),
        method='unchecked_means_any_value',
    )
    is_secret = django_filters.BooleanFilter(
        widget=CheckboxInput(),
        method='unchecked_means_any_value',
    )
    is_active = django_filters.BooleanFilter(
        widget=CheckboxInput(),
        method='unchecked_means_any_value',
    )

    def unchecked_means_any_value(self, queryset, name, value):
        if not value:
            return queryset
        return queryset.filter(**{name: value})
```

If the `value` is `False`, it will return the original QuerySet. Otherwise, it will filter the queryset with the names and values: `is_dangerous=True`, `is_secret=True`, `or is_active=True`.